# Generar archivo csv a partir de matriz (listas anidadas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tengo una matriz de 1000x5, en el formato

```
['1', 'Visa', '4539897685939002', '116', '5/2022\n']
```

Todos los valores dentro de cada fila son strings y están ordenados de forma creciente por el primer índice de cada fila, algo así:

```
['1', 'Visa', '4539897685939002', '116', '5/2022\n']
['2', 'MasterCard', '5159561932089468', '627', '2/2023\n']
```

Intento ingresar la matriz a un archivo csv, en primera instancia me salía un error que no podía escribir listas en el archivo, luego intenté ingresar las filas de esta forma

```
for linea in matriz:
   archivo.write(str(linea))
```

Todo bien hasta que abro el archivo.csv, están todas las seguidas, no en forma de tabla, así

```
['1', 'Visa', '4539897685939002', '116', '5/2022\n'],['2', 'MasterCard', '5159561932089468', '627', '2/2023\n']
```

Las 1000 lineas están seguidas ¿Cómo podría ingresar las filas en forma de tabla, tal como se supone que es una matriz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, en referencia al primer error, `write` si abres el archivo en modo texto requiere una cadena (`str`), por lo que no puedes pasar una lista. Segundo, te almacena eso porque es la representación en forma de cadena que retorna el método `__str__` de una lista, cadena que es usada también por `print`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> str(l)
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

Para generar un csv, debes ir intercalando tu separador entre cada item de la lista que forma una fila y obtener al final una sola cadena que puedas pasar a `write`. En otros casos lo recomendable es usar el módulo `csv` y [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
import csv


matriz = [['1', 'Visa', '4539897685939002', '116', '5/2022'],
          ['2', 'MasterCard', '5159561932089468', '627', '2/2023']]

with open('salida.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(matriz)
```

No obstante, en tu caso concreto tienes el carácter de nueva línea incluido en tu última columna y eso es un problema. `csv.writer` generaría un csv válido escapando la última columna, pero esto incluiría  `\n` como parte de los datos. Eso nos obliga a eliminar el salto de línea previamente, por lo que en este caso creo que lo más simple es que uses `str.join` para intercalar el separador que pienses usar en tu csv:

```
matriz = [['1', 'Visa', '4539897685939002', '116', '5/2022\n'],
          ['2', 'MasterCard', '5159561932089468', '627', '2/2023\n']]

with open('salida.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.writelines(','.join(row) for row in matriz)
```

Lo cual debe producir un fichero con el siguiente contenido:

> 1,Visa,4539897685939002,116,5/2022
>   2,MasterCard,5159561932089468,627,2/2023

Eso si, debes asegurarte de no producir un csv inválido o errado porque en este caso `csv.writer` no te protege. Por ejemplo, asegurarte de que los datos no contienen el separador.